# Those who use virtualization, is the free vmware server suitable for programmers?

Tags: vmware

is the free vmware server software suitable for programmers?

I'm a little confused between the free server version and the paid workstation version.

What is the server version really?  Can I run it on my desktop?

I've installed virtualPC by MS alerady, but want to look at vm's also.

Comment: What and why do you want to virtualize?

Comment: windowsxp, for development (.net)

Comment: commercial development? Or is this just for fun?

Answer (score 11):

Virtualisation is useful for the following:

- Building code that could crash your host machine.  Crash the VM?  Just restart it.
- Testing installers.  Take a snapshot right before installing the program and when you're done revert to the snapshot.  All traces that your program was ever there are gone and you can try again later.
- Having a second machine running a different OS to the host. I run a Mac laptop but keep a Linux VM and a VM of our product appliance available for development and testing.

Free Server:

- Clunky Web-based interface to configure and manage machines
- Slow remote display (since it travels to the client via http even on the local machine)
- Single snapshot per machine
- FREE!!!
- Runs as system service so machines run in the background without opening any windows on your desktop

Workstation:

- Improved local interface
- Faster local display
- DirectX and OpenGL support (basic) so you can actually play some Windows games or use things like AutoCad inside a VM
- Many snapshots for a machine, ability to chop and change/merge particular ones
- Runs as foreground application so you have a VMWare window open to start and manage machines.  On Linux at least you can close the interface and leave the machine running.  Haven't tried on Windows.
- Costly

Xen:

- If are happy to have a Linux host it's blazingly fast at running a supported OS.  Linux and some of the BSDs have Xen hooks now so they can para-virt easily.
- Can run a fully virtualised machine so Windows and other non-patched operating systems are supported

VirtualBox:

- Free
- Has the backing of Sun (is that a good thing?  you can decide)
- Similar to VM Workstation in functionality

Qemu:

- Free
- Pig to figure out network settigns
- Very configurable
- Can 'emulate' non X86 machines if you are doing PPC or Arm development.

Comment: The single snapshot limitation of VMware Server is a big limitation in my experience.

Comment: I have found it limiting sometimes, but for just testing installers it's actually not too bad.  If you need more you need to pay tho; VM Workstation and Parallels both have multiple snapshots but neither is free.

Comment: We're using ESXi for 20+ testing VMs, single snapshot seems to be OK. Workstation on the desktop for more complex cases tho, I think I've got about 7 multi-level snapshots on one VM at the moment so it's definetly a benefit =)

Comment: VirtualBox is free only for personal or academic use or for product evaluation. VirtualBox Open Source Edition is completely free, but lack some features present in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, it doesn't really answer your question, but I personally chose to use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) instead of VMWare, partially because of the exact issue you've run into. Trying to figure out what VMWare products I was allowed to use and how I was allowed to use them would have taken more time than getting everything set up in VirtualBox did.

Answer (score 3):

VMware Server can be run on the desktop, but there are a few things why you might want the Workstation version instead:

- It has support for debugging in the VM, using either Visual Studio or Eclipse.
- It has a better, faster user interface. VMware Server used to come with a usable console program, but the version 2 comes with a browser-based UI.
- In the most recent version you can have windows from the VM show up directly on your desktop.

A good thing with the Server version is that it runs as a service, so you can have VMs start automatically in the background, even before you log on.

Answer (score 2):

VMware Server runs as a service so is more suited to server-like tasks. It's also more restricted when it comes to interfacing with the hardware on the host machine, for example USB support was only recently added and I believe is limited to two devices.

VMware server also has (IMO) the worst configuration and management interface of all the VMware products, since it's designed to be managed remotely and is web-based.

Instead you might want to try VMware Player which is free and can run any VMware Virtual Machine. It's features are largely the same as VMware workstation, the limit being that Player is unable to create new virtual machines. This is something you do very infrequently however and there are other ways to create new machines. A Google search for "create VMware Virtual Machine" will give you plenty of options.

Comment: The standard VMWare server management console that's used for ESX will talk to the web-based server.  In fact, it's available in the free server as well, Google will show you how to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare Server is great, I use it for compartamentalizing different projects which require different setups and would recommend it if you require different environment setups and your machine has enough resources.

VMWare ESX is not free, thus not for you.
VMWare ESXi is free, but can't run on top of an OS installation, thus might not be for you.

VMWare Player plays virtual machines... but i'm not familiar with it.
(See other replies).

VMWare Workstation is only free for 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the (ESX I believe) server for free on your desktop, I would recommend it if you do multiplatform development.

For example you need to test your application in linux 32 bit and 64 bit, maybe solaris and windows aswell.

One of the things you should be careful about is that you configure everything properly. If you don't you might end up having to wait a few minutes before your OS is fully started because it loads all kinds of drivers and maybe machines on boot.

It is also nice to use as tool to create your own images, for example to mimic your production environment. This was not possible with the VM player last time I checked.

Comment: It is possible to create a new VM with player- but not easy.  You need to manually hack at the config file and use qemu-tools to make the disk image.  I haven't read the license agreement but that might be against it too.  All sounds too hard when server is free.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/computing/) and VirtualPC.

Parallels on win desktop and OS X desktop, and Virtual PC running multiple linux builds (all headless) on Server 2003.  The free VMWare is fine but I know it has some limitations.  I just found VM a bitch to setup and config when most of the other VM's work instantly out of box.

Answer (score 0):

Vmware server is meant to run mostly in the background, with a web interface for you to control the VMs.

From there you can open a remote console through a browser plugin, which is capable of doing most things you'd need it to. (Although it strangely lacks a ctrl-alt-del button) There is no hardware acceleration support in server.

Workstation runs in usermode, so you start it after logging in. It runs as an application rather than a service. It also supports multiple snapshots, if you need to rollback changes often. Server only allows one snapshot per host.

---

Personally, I have a WinXP VM in VirtualBox that I've been using for development for the past year. VBox supports seamless mode in Linux, which was the primary reason I chose it over VMWare. I believe VMWare Fusion does the other way around, seamless mode for Linux or Windows on a Mac host, but they don't support this on a Linux or Windows host to my knowledge.

It has worked well so far, just one caveat: **back up your virtual disk!** Especially if you're going to play around with snapshots. And setup a source control system outside of the virtual environment so you can get at the code if the virtual disk is inaccessible.

Comment: That's not true, I'm running the VMware free server on a Windows Server box and you can interact with the virtualized OS through a window, just like on any other desktop virtualization product.

Comment: OK, that's how it works on my Linux host. I've never used the Windows version.

Comment: @Eli: which free server? Version 1 or version 2?  Version 2 is entirely web-based with a browser plugin to actually display the machine console.
@Adam: Server supports a single snapshot per machine, taking more removes the last one.  Workstation supports taking many different snapshots.

Comment: Browser plugin is just a wrapper to install an EXE under Windows then you can use it as a normal app after that. Communication is still via network, not native/local as you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

The previous version of vmware server used the same UI as the workstation version (it seemed to support everything except snapshots).

The current version of vmware server, unfortunately has switched to a web browser based-UI which makes useful for what it's intended for, setting up virtual servers, but it's kind of clunky for doing development work.

Answer (score 0):

I use VMWare Server 2 on my development machine to run VS2008 and WSS inside Server 2003 for developing Sharepoint Web Parts.

I'm sure there are other uses for such a setup, but for my needs, it's completely sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I debated getting the "free" version of either MS or VMWare, but decided to splurge and the the $189 VMWare workstation - got to say its probably the cheapest money I have every spent. The tool is awesome, and was up and running in no time.

I can't believe I waited so long to setup vitrualization on my development machine. Once you use it, you won't think about the money you spent for more than 5 minutes.

I guess my point is don't let the small amount of money be the deciding factor in what you choose or use. This software is probably worth many thousands of dollars for the flexibility it gives you. If you can find a free tool that suits your needs, by all means use it. But, for $189 you get an unbelievable amount of value for your money.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare Workstation gets you (on top of the free version)

- Multi monitor support (you can run a VM over 2, 3, 4 monitors)
- Record/Replay debugging
- Multiple snapshots
- DirecX/3D support

I'd also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66317/which-is-the-best-vm-program-for-a-programmer

Virtualization is now a commodity product, basic simple software is free and will do the job. If you're doing software development on a commercial level day in day out, then you will really appreciate the advanced features found in Workstation.

Purchasing a VMWare Workstation license is well worth the money, it's a drop in the bucket compared to what you're paying for Visual Studio, Windows and all the other software that you're most likely using.

Answer (score 0):

For people who find this thread at a later date, its also worth adding that VMware Server is only supported on (read: only installs on) *server* OS's. I tried installing it on Vista but it didn't work. I'm pretty sure it won't intall on XP either. This may rule-out its use on a dev machine.

I use VMware Server and Workstation and they're both awesome products. My Android dev environment is in a Workstation VM and that works really well for me. I also run some old games in an XP VM and find the graphics support to be pretty good.

Comment: works great for me on Win7 btw

Comment: I've been using VMware Server 1.4 and 2.0 on WinXP for a year or two, and one of my colleagues is running Server 2.0 on Vista just fine.

Comment: qntmfred and rob: you're right and I was wrong. I think the problem I had (and it was a year ago...) was that I didn't have IIS installed, so the web-based admin console didn't work. Do you guys have IIS installed?